# Are there any polls on the new Swiss immigration referendum question?

Tags: immigration, public-opinion, referendum, switzerland

Apparently after the ["betrayal"](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-38340407) of the first [Swiss immigration-limiting referendum (of Feb 2014)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_Swiss_immigration_initiative) by their parliament, which passed a substantially watered down law (in 2016), there's now going to be another Swiss immigration referendum, as Reuters [reported in November](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-swiss-eu-immigration/swiss-cabinet-opposes-move-to-curb-eu-immigration-in-referendum-idUSKCN1NZ2KJ)

> Anti-immigration members of the Swiss People’s Party (SVP), the largest party in parliament, have pushed to end that free movement [of people from the EU] on the grounds that it leaves the country without adequate tools to manage its growing population and encroaches on its sovereignty.
>
> A referendum must be held on the matter as the required number of signatures has been gathered, but it remains unclear how much support such a proposal might garner in a nationwide vote. No date for the vote has been set.
>
> The SVP launched its drive to get a referendum held on the issue after compromise-minded lawmakers in 2016 stopped short of requiring quotas on European immigration that voters had demanded two years earlier.
>
> If the [2nd] referendum motion is passed, it would require Switzerland to unilaterally cancel free movement if the country is unable to negotiate a waiver with the EU within 12 months.

Has there been any polling of Swiss public opinion on the question that would be asked in this 2nd immigration referendum?

---

N.B. this might the 3rd+ referendum on limiting immigration; a more obscure one from Nov 2014 [rejected](https://euobserver.com/news/126729) (by a large margin) an absolute cap of immigration to 0.2% percent of the population. (If one were to count the earlier ones allowing for more immigration, e.g. the [2009 one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_Swiss_referendums#February_referendum), the count gets even more difficult.)

Comment: Is this a referendum that is upcoming?  It doesn't appear to be scheduled for May.

Comment: @JoeC: Reuters said (as quoted above) no date has been set for this one. I don't how long the Swiss  law allows for a referendum question to be postponed after it met the signature threshold (for it to be held). A [Feb 2019](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-swiss-eu/swiss-immigration-rises-again-as-ties-with-eu-face-test-idUSKCN1Q410T) piece from the same source said the same "No date for a vote has been set yet."

Answer (score 8):

**2nd EDIT:** *first polls give 2/3 rejection among population*

There are no polls for the moment. But the fact that the initiative got enough signatures pretty fast (116139 in less than 7 months; requirement: [100000 in 18 months](https://www.ch.ch/en/demokratie/political-rights/popular-initiative/how-to-launch-a-federal-popular-initiative/)) indicates that there is at least some support among Swiss citizens.

The Swiss Parliament gave its feedback on [20 December 2019](https://www.admin.ch/opc/fr/federal-gazette/2019/8179.pdf), proposed to reject the initiative (happens most of the time) and didn't draw up a counter project. The Federal Council scheduled the votation to take place on [27 September 2020](https://www.admin.ch/gov/en/start/documentation/votes/20200927/limitation-initiative.html). You can track the status of the procedure on [admin.ch](https://www.bk.admin.ch/ch/f/pore/vi/vis483.html).

(These parts of the website are only available in German, French or Italian.)

EDIT: update after the parliamentary vote

2nd EDIT: votation is scheduled and [first poll](https://www.rts.ch/info/suisse/11431280-les-suisses-jugent-positivement-les-accords-bilateraux.html) shows 69% rejection vs 29% acceptance among swiss population

Comment: What, no Romansh?

Comment: General information about initiatives are available in Romansh, but not the details about each one. A bit sad :(
But everyone in Graubünden does understand German.

Comment: I was being a little humorous about info being in “only” three languages. :)